# Practical difference between Python dict combining and JS Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, prototype

Is there any practical difference between `combo` in each snippet below?

**Python 3.5+:**

```
foo = {'name': 'foo', 'one': 1, 'two': 2}
bar = {'two': "two", 'three': 3}

bar = {**foo, **bar}

combo = bar
```

**JS (ECMAScript 2015)**:

```
var foo = {name: "foo", one: 1, two: 2};
var bar = {two: "two", three: 3};

Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, foo);

var combo = bar;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python code is simply copying the elements from the original dictionaries into a new dictionary. There's no link from the `combo` dictionary to the original `foo` and `bar` dictionaries. If you make a change to `foo` after the above code, it has no effect on `bar` or `combo`.

The Javascript code doesn't copy the object properties, it sets `foo` as the prototype of `bar` and `combo`. When you try to access a property that doesn't exist, it searches the prototype chain. If you change `foo`, the change affects `bar` and `combo` as well.

```js
var foo = {name: "foo", one: 1, two: 2};
var bar = {two: "two", three: 3};

Object.setPrototypeOf(bar, foo);

var combo = bar;

foo.x = 100;
console.log(combo.x);
```

The Javascript code that's equivalent to the Python code is:

```
var bar = Object.assign({}, bar, foo);
var combo = bar;
```

Comment: Ah! Got it. Trying to get my head around the prototype chain. Am at too early a stage to know whether I'll love it or hate it.

Comment: The most closely related concept in Python is classes and subclasses.

Comment: Yes, just realised that. Does the prototype chain allow you fall prey to the kind of complexity that comes with multiple-inheritance in Python classes?

Comment: No, it's a single inheritance chain.